# Calculate Excess/Short

Tags: sql-server-2005

i have this type of table

```
CREATE TABLE attendance
(
  Date datetime,
  Timein datetime,
  Timeout datetime,
  Spend nvarchar(50),
  excessshort nvarchar(50) 
)
```

my data look like this.

```
Date                     TimeIn                   Timeout                 Spend     excessshort
2013-01-01 00:00:00.000  2013-01-01 09:14:00.000  2013-01-01 19:06:00.000 09:52:00
```

i want to calculate excesshort

excess short comes from spent time mean a employee spent 9 hours 52 minute then its excess 00:52 minutes and if employee spent 8 hours 44 minutes then its short 00:16 minutes we have 9 to 6 hours timing shift.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick and dirty solution for you. In short, that spend column isn't of any help because it's a varchar and we need to do date math.

For demo purposes, I made a table variable with the three columns that I needed. Using the datediff function, we're going to calculate the number of minutes each person was clocked-in and then subtract the number of minutes in 9 hours (540 minutes).

If the answer in positive, then the person was clocked-in more than 9 hours. If negative, they fell short. If exactly 540 minutes, then they were on time.

Like I said, it's quick and dirty. You'll have to adapt these concepts to your specific situation. I don't know if you are trying to update a table or just run a report or something.

```
declare @attendance TABLE
(
    id int IDENTITY(1,1),
    Date datetime,
    Timein datetime,
    Timeout datetime
)
insert into @attendance (date,timein,timeout) values ('2013-01-01 00:00:00.000','2013-01-01 09:14:00.000','2013-01-01 19:06:00.000')
insert into @attendance (date,timein,timeout) values ('2013-01-01 00:00:00.000','2013-01-01 09:14:00.000','2013-01-01 17:45:00.000')
insert into @attendance (date,timein,timeout) values ('2013-01-01 00:00:00.000','2013-01-01 09:00:00.000','2013-01-01 18:00:00.000')


declare @shiftHours int, @shiftMinutes int
set @shiftHours = 9
set @shiftMinutes = @shiftHours * 60


select 
    datediff(minute,timein,timeout) as minutesClockedIn, 
    datediff(minute,timein,timeout) - @shiftMinutes as offset,
    excessOrShort =
        case 
            when (datediff(minute,timein,timeout) - @shiftMinutes) > 0 then 'excess'
            when (datediff(minute,timein,timeout) - @shiftMinutes) < 0 then 'short'
            else 'ontime'
        end,
    excessOrShortDescription =
        case 
            when (datediff(minute,timein,timeout) - @shiftMinutes) > 0
            then right('0' + cast(abs((datediff(minute,timein,timeout) - @shiftMinutes) / 60) as varchar(2)),2) + ':' + right('0' + cast(abs((datediff(minute,timein,timeout) - @shiftMinutes) % 60) as varchar(2)),2) + ' in excess'
            when (datediff(minute,timein,timeout) - @shiftMinutes) < 0
            then right('0' + cast(abs((datediff(minute,timein,timeout) - @shiftMinutes) / 60) as varchar(2)),2) + ':' + right('0' + cast(abs((datediff(minute,timein,timeout) - @shiftMinutes) % 60) as varchar(2)),2) + ' short'
            else 'ontime'
        end

from @attendance
```

This CTE version below is a little more readable, but does the same thing. I'm only using the CTE to eliminate some of the repetitive datediffs

```
declare @attendance TABLE
(
    id int IDENTITY(1,1),
    Date datetime,
    Timein datetime,
    Timeout datetime
)
insert into @attendance (date,timein,timeout) values ('2013-01-01 00:00:00.000','2013-01-01 09:14:00.000','2013-01-01 19:06:00.000')
insert into @attendance (date,timein,timeout) values ('2013-01-01 00:00:00.000','2013-01-01 09:14:00.000','2013-01-01 17:45:00.000')
insert into @attendance (date,timein,timeout) values ('2013-01-01 00:00:00.000','2013-01-01 09:00:00.000','2013-01-01 18:00:00.000')


declare @shiftHours int, @shiftMinutes int
set @shiftHours = 9
set @shiftMinutes = @shiftHours * 60
-- populate CTE for use by select statement below
;with shiftData as (
    select
        date,
        datediff(minute,timein,timeout) as minutesClockedIn, 
        datediff(minute,timein,timeout) - @shiftMinutes as totalMinutesOffset,
        excessOrShort =
            case 
                when (datediff(minute,timein,timeout) - @shiftMinutes) > 0 then 'excess'
                when (datediff(minute,timein,timeout) - @shiftMinutes) < 0 then 'short'
                else 'ontime'
            end
    from @attendance
)
-- use the CTE
select Date,
    minutesClockedIn, 
    totalMinutesOffset,
    totalMinutesOffset / 60 as hoursOffset,
    totalMinutesOffset % 60 as minutesOffset,
    excessOrShort,
    excessOrShortDescription =
        case 
            when excessOrShort in ('excess','short')
            then right('0' + cast(abs(totalMinutesOffset / 60) as varchar(2)),2) + ':' + right('0' + cast(abs(totalMinutesOffset % 60) as varchar(2)),2) + ' ' + excessOrShort
            else 'ontime'
        end
from shiftData
```